# Object[] can not be fetched, java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have this piece of code:

```
Object[] cells = null;
            for (Station s : allStationOfOneGraph) {
                System.out.println("NEXT");
                for (Station s1 : allStationOfOneGraph) {
                    cells = graph.getEdgesBetween(s, s1); 
                    System.out.println(cells); //**This works fine and give me a lot of information**
System.out.println(cells.length);//**This gives me 0** !!!!                 
for (Object cell : cells) {

//Here nothing works
                        Line l = (Line) cell;
                        System.out.println(l.getId());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any help?

**UPDATE:**

Here some output example when i print all `cells`  (the output of `graph.getEdgesBetween`):

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@d6f470
[Ljava.lang.Object;@49e998
[Ljava.lang.Object;@872770
[Ljava.lang.Object;@12e5985
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1f741ef
[Ljava.lang.Object;@9d1b1
[Ljava.lang.Object;@a5d627
[Ljava.lang.Object;@18ed438
[Ljava.lang.Object;@eb49d
[Ljava.lang.Object;@173c0e2
[Ljava.lang.Object;@7c70a5
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1c77b8e
[Ljava.lang.Object;@180d3a1
[Ljava.lang.Object;@c5fd22
[Ljava.lang.Object;@6dd711
[Ljava.lang.Object;@142a584
[Ljava.lang.Object;@808b17
[Ljava.lang.Object;@12badee
[Ljava.lang.Object;@a8171f
[Ljava.lang.Object;@186197d
[Ljava.lang.Object;@f3678e
[Ljava.lang.Object;@13c10c
[Ljava.lang.Object;@e72e28
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1876b89
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1a51f57
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1acbce3
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1a4f9b0
[Ljava.lang.Object;@4b795
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1b0cfa0
[Ljava.lang.Object;@10f4ec3
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1fc224c
[Ljava.lang.Object;@2fdac2
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1c2f9ba
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1993ad5
[Ljava.lang.Object;@e58b49
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1b6b35
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1b97eb
[Ljava.lang.Object;@192e83b
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1ccb2b7
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e9178f
[Ljava.lang.Object;@9c6e2
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e03f3f
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1587c88
[Ljava.lang.Object;@57c87c
[Ljava.lang.Object;@12b66eb
```

Comment: Nothing works means what exactly? Compile errors?

Comment: What does "This works fine and give me a lot of information" mean? What is the actual "a lot of information" it gives you?

Comment: what is return type of **graph.getEdgesBetween(s, s1);**

Comment: It gives me the objects, but I can't fetch them one by one

Comment: What is the type of the objects?

Comment: ` System.out.println(cells); //**This works fine and give me a lot of information**` This give you the hashcode value.

Comment: If `println(cells)` works and `println(cells.length)` returns zero, it means that you have misspelled `cells` in one of the two places.

Comment: `Object[] com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph.getEdgesBetween(Object source, Object target)`

Comment: Is it `cells` or `celles`???

Comment: `graph.getEdgesBetween` returns Object[]

Comment: The object is an `mxCell` object of JGraph Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Object[]` doesn't define any user-friendly `toString` method. When printing out your `cells` variable, I am pretty sure you get something like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@2bbd86`

This doesn't guarantee the fact that your array contains data.

For instance, the code:

```
System.out.println(new Object[]{});
```

will print:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@2bbd86
```

But the array is empty.

Even when the array is not empty, you will get the same output as previously.
For instance:

```
System.out.println(new Object[]{new Object(), new Object()});
```

will print

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@2bbd86
```

The fact that you get many lines is only due to your for loop:

`for (Station s1 : allStationOfOneGraph)`

Answer (score 3):

Check graph.getEdgesBetween(s, s1); this may be returning empty object[] and hence System.out.println(cells.length); gives 0 and hence following for loop is not getting executed and you don't get any thing

```
for (Object cell : cells) {

//Here nothing works
                        Line l = (Line) cell;
                        System.out.println(l.getId());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Pllease have a look at the updates : ), `graph.getEdgesBetween(s, s1)` does not give me an empty Object[]

Comment: @HoussemBdr You say in your code that `System.out.println(cells.length);//**This gives me 0** !!!!` that sounds like an empty array to me

Comment: from update you come to know that object[] return via graph.getEdgesBetween(s, s1) is not null thats it....but it doesn't tell whether the object[] contains anything....

Answer (score 1):

Your output of cells means something different to what you think it means

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@d6f470
[Ljava.lang.Object;@49e998
[Ljava.lang.Object;@872770
[Ljava.lang.Object;@12e5985
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1f741ef
```

Each one of these simply means; this is an object of type [Ljava.lang.Object (the name for an array) and it is at memory address @d6f470<sup>1</sup>. **It says nothing about how big the array is**.

```
System.out.println(cells.length);//**This gives me 0** !!!!
```

This line on the other hand tells you the size of the array, namely zero. Now the array still exists, it is not null, but it is of size zero. As such when you iterate over it you get 0 elements.

Why it's zero is contained elsewhere in your code.

#### Notes

<sup>1</sup> It's actually much more complicated than just a memory address, but we can consider it that